# Android: .getDrawable deprecated, minimum SDK 17 solution?

Tags: java, android

I am currently reading through the Head First Android Development book.

This question is regarding code in chapter 13, with a link to the specific file below:

https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/blob/master/chapter14/BitsAndPizzas/app/src/main/java/com/hfad/bitsandpizzas/CaptionedImagesAdapter.java

The code below uses a deprecated method, .getDrawable:

```
Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
```

For new SDKs this can be resolved by changing the code to:

```
Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position], null);
```

However, I cannot get the code working for a minimum SDK of 17, and have tried using ContextCompat. The previously used compatibility solution I found was deprecated.

Thank you

Comment: "and have tried using ContextCompat" -- and what specific problem are you encountering with that? Beyond that, you are welcome to use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` and use the two-parameter method or one-parameter method as appropriate.

Comment: "if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position], null);
        }
        else 
        {
            Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);"

The second .getDrawable is still deprecated.

For ContextCompat:

"Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().ContextCompat.getDrawable(null, imageIds[position]);"

The contextCompat is red with the line: cannot resolve symbol 'ContextCompat'

Comment: "The .getDrawable within the else statement is still deprecated" -- of course. "Deprecated" means "we have something else that we would like you to consider to use". When they deprecate something because they added a replacement in a newer Android version, you still use the "deprecated" method on older versions of Android, because time machines don't exist and we cannot "ret-con" Android to change the older devices. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise it would let me compile and use it. Thank you!

Comment: `ContextCompat` is a separate class with a static `getDrawable` method that provides a backwards-compatible bridge to the new `Context.getDrawable` method. It is not a literal copy-and-paste replacement for the deprecated getDrawable().

You would add the support-v4 library as a dependency for your project and then call `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageIds[position])` with an appropriate `Context` object.

Comment: What would be an appropriate context object?

Answer (score 3):

[`ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)) is not deprecated and is the correct method to use in this scenario.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use `ContextCompat`, you can always just use [the same code it uses](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#L307-L325):

```
public static final Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 21) {
        return context.getDrawable(id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio cannot resolve: 
ContextCompatApi21,
context.

What do I need to import?

Also, what do I place in context, as before I only expected to use the id parameter?

I have nothing against using ContextCompat, but that was also giving a cannot resolve issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to replace that. I have updated my answer. For reference, `ContextCompatApi21`  is also in the support library, and [the source is here](https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support/blob/master/support-v4/src/main/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompatApi21.java).